# Erro em Sintaxe mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou fazendo uma página para listar os produtos que tenho  em meu banco de dados, porém ao carregar a págia recebo esse erro que não consigo resolver:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\loja\produto-lista.php on line 7

Linha onde está o erro:

```
while($produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
```

Quando tento executar o código sem o `while` recebo o mesmo erro.

Código completo:

```
<?php include("cabecalho.php"); ?>
<?php include("conecta.php");
function listaProdutos($conexao) {
    $produtos = array();
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from produtos");

    while($produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        array_push($produtos, $produto);
    }

    return $produtos;

}


$produtos = listaProdutos($conexao);
?>



<?php include("rodape.php")?>
```

Conecta.php :

```
<?php
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou passar o nome do banco de dados [no momento da conexão](http://php.net/mysqli_connect):

```
mysqli_connect("localhost", "seu_user", "sua_senha", "nome_do_banco");
```